# Файл забивается мусором, а при завершении программы происходит аварийная остановка

Tags: c++

Пытался написать свой тип файла позволяющий хранить в нём другие файлы.

> P.S. Я никогда таким не занимался и делаю это впервые, прошу не швыряться тапками.

Компилируется все замечательно, но падает с ошибкой `free(): double free detected in tcache 2 Аварийный останов (стек памяти сброшен на диск)`

Всего в проекте 3 файла

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gymfile.h"

 int main()
 {
    gymdata teser("Hello hi","Some data");
    gymdata ass("Another File","Some data");

    gymfile test("gamefile.gym",false);

    test.writeData(teser);    
    test.writeData(ass);

    test.closeFile();

    gymfile testa("gamefile.gym",true); 
    gymdata popka(testa.getData(0));    

 }
```

`gymdata.h`

```
#define GYMD
#ifdef GYMD

class gymdata
{
    protected:
    char name[255];
    std::vector <char> rawdata;
    
    public:
    char *getData(){
        return &rawdata[0];
    }
    char *getName(){
        return name;
    }
    void setName(char *nname){
        strcpy(name,nname);
    }
    void resize(int size){
        rawdata.resize(size);
    }
    void addbyte(char byte){
        resize(rawdata.size()+1);
        rawdata[rawdata.size()]=byte;
    }
    int getArraySize(){
        return rawdata.size();
    }
    gymdata(const char *nname,const char *dt=""){
        if(strlen(nname)>255) return;
        if (strcmp(dt,"")==0) return;
        memset(name,0,255);
        strcpy(name,nname);
        resize(strlen(dt));
        for(int i=0;i<=(strlen(dt));i++){
            rawdata[i]=dt[i];
        }
    }
    gymdata(const gymdata &dtb){
        rawdata.resize(dtb.rawdata.size()+1);
        rawdata = dtb.rawdata;
        strcpy(name,dtb.name);
    }
};
#endif
```

`gymfile.h`

```
#define GYMF
#ifdef GYMF
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include "gymdata.h"
class gymfile{
    private:
    std::uint16_t files[1024];
    char name[255];
    FILE *writef;
    FILE *readf;
    std::string fname;
    bool newfile{false};
    bool rw;
    
    std::uint16_t getFileStartAddr(int fn){
        if (fn>511) return 0;
        return files[fn*2];
    }
    std::uint16_t getFileEndAddr(int fn){
        if(fn>511) return 0;
        return files[fn*2+1];
    }
    public:
    void openFileWrite(std::string name){
        for(int i=0; i<=1024; i++){
            files[i]=0;
        }
        fname=name;
        writef = fopen(name.c_str(),"wb");
        if(fopen(name.c_str(), "wb")==NULL){
            fclose(writef);
            return;
        }
        fseek(writef,0,SEEK_END);
        if(2048>ftell(writef)){
            newfile=true;
        }
        fseek(writef,0,SEEK_SET);
    }

    void openFileRead(std::string name){
        for(int i=0; i<=1024; i++){
            files[i]=0;
        }
        readf = fopen(name.c_str(),"rb");
        fread(files,sizeof(std::uint16_t),1024,readf);
    }

    void closeFile(){
        if (rw==true) fclose(writef); else
        fclose(readf);
    }


    gymdata getData(int filen){
        if (getFileStartAddr(filen)==0) return gymdata("Unknown File","This file not exists");
        char filname[255];
        fseek(readf,getFileStartAddr(filen),SEEK_SET);
        fread(filname,sizeof(char),255,readf);
        fseek(readf,256,SEEK_CUR);
        std::vector<char> data;
        data.resize(getFileEndAddr(filen)-getFileStartAddr(filen));
        memset(&data[0],0,data.size());
        fread(&data[0],sizeof(char),getFileEndAddr(filen)-getFileStartAddr(filen),readf);
        std::cout<<filname<<"\n"<<&data[0]<<std::endl;
        return gymdata(filname,&data[0]);
    }
    gymdata getData(char *filen){

    }
    void writeData(gymdata dat){
        fseek(writef,0,SEEK_SET);
        int i=0;
        while(i!=1024 && files[i]!=0){
            i++;
        }
        if(i-1<0){
            files[i]=2049;
            files[i+1]=files[i]+dat.getArraySize()+255;
            fseek(writef,2049,SEEK_SET);
        } else{
            files[i]=files[i-1]+1;
            files[i+1]=files[i]+dat.getArraySize()+255;
            fseek(writef,files[i-1]+1,SEEK_SET);
        }
        fwrite(dat.getName(),sizeof(char),255,writef);
        fseek(writef,256,SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(dat.getData(),sizeof(char),dat.getArraySize(),writef);
        sync();
    }
    void sync(){
        fseek(writef,0,SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(files,sizeof(std::uint16_t),1024,writef);
    }
    gymfile(std::string finame="",bool read=true){
        if(read){
            rw=false;
        }else{
            rw=true;
        }
        if(finame!=""){
            if(!read){
                openFileWrite(finame);
            } else{
                openFileRead(finame);
            }
        }
    }

    ~gymfile(){
        closeFile();
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: допустим вы вызываете closeFile - что тогда происходит в деструкторе?

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка здесь

```
resize(strlen(dt));
for(int i=0;i<=(strlen(dt));i++){
    rawdata[i]=dt[i];
}
```

либо в resize(strlen(dt)); на одиницу больше, либо цикл исправьте.

Во вторых - инициализируйте свои переменные. Всегда.
Потому что [fclose](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fclose), который получил шальной указатель, не будет работатать

> he behavior is undefined if the value of the pointer stream is used after fclose returns.

[А также, fclose не любит nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443164/fclose-causing-segmentation-fault).

Вывод - используйте плюсовые классы и функции и будет и понятнее, и проще.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, как именно здесь использовать плюсовые классы и функции, про fstream нету нормальной информации как работать в бинарном режиме.

Comment: что конкретно Вам не понятно?  вот https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream достаточно информации и примеров

Comment: И все равно, толком ничего. Там предлагают поступать как у меня используя `std::FILE`

Answer (score -2):

Этот код врятли удастся заставить работать когда-либо. В нём почти в каждой строке есть ошибка.

Причём некоторые специально добавлены: `for(int i=0; i<=1024; i++)`

Вот списочек, и это только то, что смог найти сам компилятор.

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Предупреждение  C26447  Функция объявлена как "noexcept", но вызывает функцию "closeFile()", которая может порождать исключения (f.6).  Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  134 Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "main" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  138 Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::sync" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).  Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  114 Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::openFileRead" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).  Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  64  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::getFileStartAddr" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).  Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  38  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::getFileEndAddr" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  42  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::getData" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  91  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymfile::closeFile" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6). Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  72  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymdata::gymdata" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  22  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymdata::getName" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  23  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymdata::getData" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  25  Активные
Предупреждение  C26440  Функция "gymdata::getArraySize" может быть объявлена как "noexcept" (f.6).  Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  24  Активные
Предупреждение  C26495  Переменная "gymfile::files" не инициализирована. Всегда инициализируйте переменную-член (type.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  118 Активные
Предупреждение  C26455  Конструктор по умолчанию не может выдавать исключения (throw). Объявите его как "noexcept" (f.6).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  118 Активные
Предупреждение  C26477  Используйте "nullptr" вместо 0 или NULL (es.47).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  23  Активные
Предупреждение  C26477  Используйте "nullptr" вместо 0 или NULL (es.47).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  53  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  40  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  44  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  49  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  66  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  86  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  87  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  88  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  89  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  97  Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  101 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  102 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  102 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  105 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  105 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  106 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  106 Активные
Предупреждение  C26446  Использовать gsl::at() вместо непроверенного оператора с нижним индексом (bounds.4).    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  107 Активные
Предупреждение  C6201   Индекс "1024" находится вне диапазона от "0" до "1023" для буфера "this->files", возможно, размещенного в стеке.    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  49  Активные
Предупреждение  C6201   Индекс "1024" находится вне диапазона от "0" до "1023" для буфера "this->files", возможно, размещенного в стеке.    Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  66  Активные
Предупреждение  C26432  Если вы определяете или удаляете какие-либо операции по умолчанию в типе "class gymfile", определите или удалите их все (c.21). Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  133 Активные
Предупреждение  C26485  Выражение "this->files": не допускайте вырождения массива в указатель (bounds.3).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  69  Активные
Предупреждение  C26485  Выражение "this->files": не допускайте вырождения массива в указатель (bounds.3).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  116 Активные
Предупреждение  C26485  Выражение "filname": не допускайте вырождения массива в указатель (bounds.3).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  82  Активные
Предупреждение  C26485  Выражение "filname": не допускайте вырождения массива в указатель (bounds.3).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  88  Активные
Предупреждение  C26485  Выражение "filname": не допускайте вырождения массива в указатель (bounds.3).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  89  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  40  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  44  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  49  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  66  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  97  Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  101 Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  102 Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  105 Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  106 Активные
Предупреждение  C26482  В качестве индексов массивов используйте только константные выражения (bounds.2).   Test    F:\f_prog\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp  107 Активные
```

Вывод: Использование в С++ функций из C не привело ни к чему хорошему.

Comment: в приведенном выводе нет ни одного сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: @KoVadim как минимум C6201 указал на гарантированный UB. А остальные показывают на то, где почти 100% неправильный код.